# C# List<string> only prints last element

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-studio

I'm new to c# and appreciate all the help i can get.
I have this problem where I want to print all elements in a list but I only get the last element as output. If I use "+=" instead of "=" I get all the elements as one line which is something I don´t prefer.

How do I print all the elements on their own row?

The Code:

```
  public override string ToString()
  {        
        string combindedstring = string.Empty;

        foreach (string array in foodDescriptionList)
        {
            combindedstring = array;
        }      

        return combindedstring;
    }
```

Also I'm new to this website. If anything is inappropriate with my question, let me know. Thanks for all help :).

Comment: Try this : combindedstring += array;

Comment: When i use that i get the all the elements in one line.
 I want to display the different elements on their own row.

Comment: Are you implementing your own collection?

Comment: All the responses are better than that but str += "\n" + newStr should work on your code. But complicated to check for the first element to don't have new line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2) and avoid the loop all together.

Use the option below to put each entry on its own line (using `Environment.NewLine`):

```
// return list separated by new line character
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, foodDescriptionList);
}
```

The code below is another option and will separate each item using a `,`:

```
// return list separated by ,
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Join(", ", foodDescriptionList);
}
```

In the overload above `string.Join` takes 2 arguments: `string.Join(separator, array)`. The microsoft documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If the first alternative still prints the elements as one line. Can i assume that the problem is somewhere else in my code?

Comment: @wixner how are you displaying the data? how many items are in `foodDescriptionList`? If there is more than one element in the list then it should be output on multiple lines

Comment: I use a listbox. And the number of elements differs.

Comment: A listbox has an `Items` collection.  You'll need to populate the collection with your array/list. One way is `listbox.DataSource = foodDescriptionList`.

Comment: How does that work if my list is in a seperate class? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190147/discussion-between-haldo-and-wixner).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you in each loop iteration override the previous value so at the end you only take the last value from the collection. Instead, use `StringBuilder` and append each element to it.

```
public override string ToString()
{        
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string array in foodDescriptionList)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(array); //sb.AppendJoin(", ", array); if you want to add separator
    }      

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

---

There are plenty of solutions but this one emphasizes the problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use += and add New Line at the end, something like this:

combindedstring += array + Environment.NewLine;